# Why do we drink wine on Purim?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Why do people have a custom of drinking *davka* wine on Purim? After all, the story took place in שושן הבירה - Shushan of Beer (Ester 1:2)!

Why do people drink wine instead of beer then?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer:

The Royal Rav ordained that Achashverush should always have only the Rav's cerified wine readily available, as it says (Esther 1:7):

וְיֵין מַלְכוּת רָב, כְּיַד הַמֶּלֶךְ

The kingdom's rabbi's wine was near the king's hand. (i.e. - available)

Kal Vachomer - if Achashverush who was a Goy had the rav's wine next to him for his party, shouldn't we have it for our party?

Answer (score 2):

It's because "ארור המן" has the same *gimatriya* as "יין".

Comment: Upvote this comment if you, too, upvoted this answer without checking the gematriya ;-)

Comment: By my count, they are 502 and 70, respectively. @Shokhet

Comment: @Cnsersmoit Scimonster that's okay, the difference is 256, and you're allowed to be off by 256 in _gimatriya_.

Comment: @msh210 - I might upvote this, but only if I don't know about Arur Mordechai, and you don't know about Baruch Haman :-)  Or, is it the other way around? I can't recall...